# How can i add an entry to a specific index in a list?

Tags: dart

I can call list.add() which adds at the end but there is no convenient way to add an entry to a specific index which at the same time grows the list.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [insertRange](http://api.dartlang.org/dart_core/List.html#insertRange), it will grow the list when adding new elements.

```dart
var list = ["1","3","4"];
list.insertRange(0, 1, "0");
list.insertRange(2, 1, "2");
list.forEach((e) => print(e));
```

You can try it out on the DartBoard [here](http://try.dartlang.org/s/QcM4)

Comment: `insertRange` method was replaced by `insert()` and `insertAll()`. See: http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html

Answer (score 36):

Dart 2

```
var idx = 3;
list.insert(idx, 'foo');
```

Depends on whether you want to insert a single item or a bunch of items

- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/insert.html
- https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/insertAll.html

All available methods https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List-class.html#instance-methods

Comment: list.insert(...) increases the length of list by 1

Comment: however, I tried it on the dartpad that is not the case, any specific scenario when the list length increases by 1?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `insert()` and `removeAt()` methods now.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it seams as if list.insertRange(index, range, [elem]) is what i am looking for.

Comment: The **range** attribute didn't make sense to me. They should make something like **insertAtPosition()** and **replaceAtPosition()**

Comment: Josh Bloch is working on revamping the Dart collection libraries right now, so `insert()` and `removeAt()` should be coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

Answer given by [**Lars Tackmann**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231211/lars-tackmann) was absolutely right
but now this method not available in DART.
Watch new method insert and insertAll.

```
void main() {

    final list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; 
    
    // insert at particular indexed
    list.insert(2,50); // (index,value)
    // output : [1, 2, 50, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    //  as you sow value 50 inserted at index 2 
    
    final list2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; 
    // insert list inside list at perticular indexed 
    final allList = [11,22,33]; 
  
    // allList add at index = 3 in list2 
    list2.insertAll(3,allList); 
    
    // output : [1, 2, 3, 11, 22, 33, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]  
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
void insert(int index, E element);
```

Inserts all objects of [iterable] at position [index] in this list.
This increases the length of the list by the length of [iterable] and
shifts all later objects towards the end of the list.
The list must be growable.
The [index] value must be non-negative and no greater than [length].