# How to insert an element at an index in list?

Tags: dart, flutter

This [question was asked in 2012 and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966430/how-can-i-add-an-entry-to-a-specific-index-in-a-list) was to use `insertRange`. Is there any way to do it now?

Comment: [insertAll](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/List/insertAll.html) has the index parameter that does what you want.